# How do I find the location of the file via inspect element?

Tags: javascript, java, php, html, wordpress

So I want to edit a small thing in my website and I can change it via Inspect Element without a problem, but I can't find the location of the file in order to change it. That's the website: gesher-jds.org/giving

I tried everything..I searched in all the folders and I couldn't find the small thing that I need to edit. I want to change: give-gateway-offline-2727-1 to give-gateway-offline-2727-2

I tried to find it all day and I couldn't..

```
<input type="radio" name="payment-mode" class="give-gateway" id="give-gateway-offline-2727-2" value="offline">
```

Comment: When you say "searched in all the folders", have you tried to open the full project in an IDE and search inside the code? That may be the easiest way to find what you need.

Comment: I used Notepad ++ in order to search inside the code and I couldn't find it.

Comment: It is coming from your `give form` Plugin.

Comment: 2727-1, this might be a dynamically generated number

Answer (score 0):

Id generation logic seems dynamically generating like,
id = "give-gateway-offline-" + id-number

Where id-number may be calculated to 2727-1.

Instead of searching the codebase directly for "give-gateway-offline-2727-1", try to search with sub strings. Eg. give-gateway-offline

Comment: Still can't find it. The only thing I found is:  if ( true === $is_payment_method_visible ) { ?> <li<?php echo $checked_class; ?>> <input type="radio" name="payment-mode" class="give-gateway" id="give-gateway-<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway_id . '-' . $id_prefix ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway_id ); ?>"<?php echo $checked; ?>>

Answer (score 0):

In your case Id is dynamically generated.
use visual code for searching and instead of searching direct id you can search other related tag like **class="give-gateway"** and find the where logic is write for dynamic ID build and change it.

Comment: That's the only thing I found: if ( true === $is_payment_method_visible ) { ?> <li<?php echo $checked_class; ?>> <input type="radio" name="payment-mode" class="give-gateway" id="give-gateway-<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway_id . '-' . $id_prefix ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway_id ); ?>"<?php echo $checked; ?>>

Comment: Can you give me the detail about  id="give-gateway-<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway_id . '-' . $id_prefix ); so i can help you more

Comment: id="give-gateway-<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway_id . '-' . $id_prefix ); output of this code is - > give-gateway-offline-2727-1 & give-gateway-authorize-2727-1 for two different radio button, here your $gateway_id is change offline or authorize & $id_prefix is 2727-1 is remain same all time i think it is set default on database or some other place so you can find that place and change it to 2727-2

Comment: if your problem has been solved, please don't forget to tick my answer as correct answer. @starwars400